# Prove the limit superior of a bounded sequence converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, proof-verification, supremum-and-infimum

Let $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ be a bounded sequence and $b_n = \sup\{a_k\ |\ k \geq n\}$. Prove $b_n$ converges. This is the limit superior of $(a_n) := \limsup\ a_n$.

Wanted to see if my proof made sense.

- Since $a_n$ is bounded, we know $\exists\ M \in \mathbb{R}$ such that
  $|a_n| \leq M\ \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$.
- $(b_n)$ converges to $x \in \mathbb{R}$ if $\forall \epsilon > 0,
     \exists\ N \in\ \mathbb{N}\ \forall n \in \mathbb{N}, n \geq N
     \implies |b_n-x| < \epsilon$.

Since $(a_n)$ is bounded, by completeness of $\mathbb{R}$ and non empty by assumption, we know that since it has an upper bound, it has a least upperbound, that is the supremum.

So we know past some $K$, $a_k$ = $S$, where $S$ denotes the supremum of all elements in the sequence. So for sequence is eventually constant, that is constant for $n \geq K$. And so converges to $S$.

Comment: Hint: the sequence $(b_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is increasing and bounded. Your conclusion on the $a_k$ is false -- just take $a_{k} = 1/k$ for example.

Comment: Increasing and bounded means we can use the monotone convergence theorem. So follows from there I suppose.

Comment: @weirdo $b_n$ is decreasing of course.

Comment: ^ Was about to note. If we were referring to the limit inferior, then it'd be increasing as I understand. But decreasing for this case.

Comment: @SS' Yes for the liminf $I_n$ is increasing and the same argument applies.

Comment: @SS' You're right, my bad!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that

- $b_n$ is bounded, since $a_n$ is bounded

and

- $b_n$ is decreasing since by the definition $b_{n+1}\le b_n$

then refer to [Monotone convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem).